# node js not behaving the same way on local and Google App Egine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cesiumjs

I'm developing an app to upload .las file to cesium ion.

I have modified this code https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium-ion-rest-api-examples/blob/main/tutorials/rest-api/index.js
To pass a file from the browser.

It's working flawlessly when I run npm start on my local env.

When I try the same thing on the app Engine, I do not get the message about where the process is at. It's does upload the file though. It's just I can't monitor what is going on.

To explain what is going on below, I send a file from the client, then it's catch by `app.post("/upload"`
Then, it create asset on Ion, and then upload to S3, then it tell ion it's finished, then it monitor the tiling on Ion.
Then I call every second `app.post("/progress"` That is sending back the stat of things to the client.

I think there is probably a logic I'm missing, something basic I make totally wrong. I'm using one single service for both the backend and the frontend. Can this be a part of the problem ?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const rawdatafr = require('./lang/fr.json');
const rawdataen = require('./lang/en.json');
const axios = require('axios').default;
const accessToken = process.env.REACT_APP_ION_TOKEN;

const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

var urlLang = (environment === 'development') ? 'client/src/lang/' : 'lang/'; 
console.log('urlLang ?  '+urlLang);


app.use(cors());
app.use(fileUpload({
  useTempFiles: true,
  safeFileNames: false,
  preserveExtension: true,
  tempFileDir: 'temp/'
}));
'use strict';

var messageFromLoc = rawdataen;
var input = null;
var filename = null;
var srcType = 'POINT_CLOUD';
var message = null;
var needMonitoring = false;
var assetMetadata = null;
var finished = null;
 
function resetGlobalvar(){
    message = null;
    needMonitoring = false;
    assetMetadata = null;
    finished = null;
    input = null;
    filename = null;
    srcType = 'POINT_CLOUD';
}

async function creat_asset(){
    finished = false;
    message = 'create asset';
    axios.post('https://api.cesium.com/v1/assets', {
        name: filename,
        description: '',
        type: '3DTILES',
        options: {
            position:[ 2.29, 48.85, 0.1],
            sourceType: srcType,
        }
      },{
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        message = 'created successfully :> send to s3';
        sendtos3(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        message = error;
      });
}

async function sendtos3(response){
    console.log('Asset created.');
    message = 'send to s3';
    try{
        const uploadLocation = response.uploadLocation;
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({
            apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
            region: 'us-east-1',
            signatureVersion: 'v4',
            endpoint: uploadLocation.endpoint,
            credentials: new AWS.Credentials(
                uploadLocation.accessKey,
                uploadLocation.secretAccessKey,
                uploadLocation.sessionToken)
        });

        let params =  {
            Body: fs.createReadStream(input),
            Bucket: uploadLocation.bucket,
            Key: uploadLocation.prefix+filename
        };
    
        let s3Response = await s3.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function (progress) {
            message = `${messageFromLoc.upload}: ${((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100).toFixed(2)}%`;
            console.log(`Upload: ${((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100).toFixed(2)}%`);
        }).promise();
        // request successed
        console.log(`File uploaded to S3 at ${s3Response.Bucket} bucket. File location: ${s3Response.Location}`);
        message = `File uploaded to S3 at ${s3Response.Bucket} bucket. File location: ${s3Response.Location}`;
        step3(response);
        // return s3Response.Location; 
    }
    // request failed
    catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
        message = ex;
    }
}
async function step3(response){
    const onComplete = response.onComplete;
    assetMetadata = response.assetMetadata;
    message = 'step3';
    axios.post(onComplete.url, onComplete.fields,{
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        message = 'step3 done';
        monitorTiling(assetMetadata);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        message = error;
      });
}

async function monitorTiling(assetMetadata){
    // console.log(response);
    const assetId = assetMetadata.id;
    message = 'monitorTiling';
    axios.get(`https://api.cesium.com/v1/assets/${assetId}`,{headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }})
        .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        console.log('monitorTiling - success');
        var status = response.data.status;
        message = 'Tiling - success';
        if (status === 'COMPLETE') {
            console.log('Asset tiled successfully');
            console.log(`View in ion: https://cesium.com/ion/assets/${assetMetadata.id}`);
            message = 'Asset tiled successfully';
            needMonitoring = false;
            finished = true;
        } else if (status === 'DATA_ERROR') {
            console.log('ion detected a problem with the uploaded data.');
            message = 'ion detected a problem with the uploaded data.';
            needMonitoring = false;
            finished = true;
        } else if (status === 'ERROR') {
            console.log('An unknown tiling error occurred, please contact support@cesium.com.');
            message = 'An unknown tiling error occurred, please contact support@cesium.com.';
            needMonitoring = false;
            finished = true;
        } else {
            needMonitoring = true;
            if (status === 'NOT_STARTED') {
                console.log('Tiling pipeline initializing.');
                message = 'Tiling pipeline initializing.';
            } else { // IN_PROGRESS
                console.log(`Asset is ${assetMetadata.percentComplete}% complete.`);
                message = `Asset is ${assetMetadata.percentComplete}% complete.`;
            }
        }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
        message =error;
        })
}
 
/*------- LISTEN FOR CALL TO UPLOAD AND START THE UPLOAD PROCESS ----------*/
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
    if (!req.files) {
        res.send("File was not found");
        message = 'File was not found';
        return;
    }
    input = req.files.file.tempFilePath;
    filename = req.files.file.name;
    emptyTempFolder('temp', input.replace('temp/', ''));
    
    var ext = path.extname(filename);
    if(ext=='.zip'){
        srcType = 'CITYGML';
    }
    /*------- START UPLOAD PROCESS ----------*/
    creat_asset();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

/*------- LISTEN FOR PROGRESS TO UPLOAD ASSET ----------*/
app.get("/progress", (req, res) => {
    // lang = req.get('Accept-Language').substring(0, 2).toLowerCase();
    // if(lang=='fr'){
    //     messageFromLoc = rawdatafr;
    // }
    console.log('message  ='+message);
    if(needMonitoring){
        monitorTiling(assetMetadata);
    }

    res.json({ message: message, done: finished, myAssetMetadata: assetMetadata });
    if(finished){
        resetGlobalvar();
    }
});

/*--------------STATIC ----------------*/
app.use(express.static( path.join(__dirname, 'build' )));
```

And my app.yaml is like this :

```
runtime: nodejs14
env: standard
includes:
  - env_variables.yaml
instance_class: B1
service: my-app
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 25
  idle_timeout: 60m
```

Comment: You definitely need to provide more information - error message, are you on GAE standard or flex, maybe your app.yaml, the part of your code where you think the error might be coming from

Comment: Hi @NoCommandLine, I just shared the code and the app.yaml file.

Comment: Are you saying you don't see the output from the different ```console.log``` statements you have in the code (i.e. in Production)?

Comment: I use a global variable, ( var message ), that is supposed to be changed trough the upload process, and send back to the client when the server catch the app.post("/progress". with res.json({ message: message, done: finished, myAssetMetadata: assetMetadata }); I send get request from client to server every second to monitor the upload progress. But on the app Engine, the message received by the client is always empty, or sending the success message, even though the process is not finished.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is from your instance(s). You're using basic scaling with up to 25 instances.

It looks like a combination of the following is happening

a) When you send a request to `/progress`, a new instance of your App is created which means all of the global variables are starting from their default values (the initial value of message is `null`).

b) Other times, a request to `/progress` is handled by an existing instance which was already processing an upload request and that request has completed and so the message says `completed`

You don't have this problem on your local environment because only 1 instance runs.

To test this theory, modify your `app.yaml` and set `max_instances: 1`. This is supposed to force the App to only use 1 instance which means subsequent requests should use an existing instance (which has the updated state of your global variables)

Comment: Thanks !!! I have no idea how instance works, so I'm very glad you explained it with simple terms :) I will update has you say asap, and tell you what happens.

Comment: Ok, so I tried with max_instances: 1, it didn't work, the message was not updated, and the file not uploaded at all. Didn't even get an error message. I changed the app.yaml back to env: flex and remove all basic_scaling and services, it's back to uploading, sending some message, some time, but in this weird erratic way. Am I doing this the right way ? sending regular request to the server to check the progress ? I feel there should be a better way to do this...

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying the only thing you changed from your App that was previously uploading (just not displaying all the monitoring messages) was setting ```max_instances :1```, and after that change, the upload no longer worked?

Comment: Yes. with max_instances :1, the upload is failing, and I don't get any error message.

Comment: I'll try with max_instances :2, just in case, there is one running for the front, I will keep you posted.

Comment: Ok, So I tried with max_instances :2, I got a 500 error, 3, 4, and 5 gave me the same result. It actually only upload my 28mb in the flex env.